# enyzme call react method and expect output got undefined?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, chai, enzyme

enzyme called react function got undefined in the return? It's called but can I call it with props like below to call the spy function? I'm using chai with enzyme.

```
//class
export class MyComponent extends Component {
  printSomething = () => 'output'
  render() {
    return (
      <div></div>
    );
  }
}

//spec
describe.only('"handleChange" method', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    const MyComponent = mount(<MyComponent />)
    sinon.spy(MyComponent.instance(), 'printSomething')
  })
  it('should call and test printSomething output', () => {

    //some simutlation.. 

    //called
    expect(MyComponent.instance().printSomething).to.have.been.called()

    //failed here? got undefined?
    expect(MyComponent.instance().printSomething()).to.be.equal('output')
  })
```

Comment: Is `.to.have.equal` a typo? If not, could be the problem. Probably want `to.equal`

Comment: @TadasAntanavicius fixed the typo

Comment: Looks like you changed it to `to.be.equal`, which I would still expect to throw an error (possibly the one you're getting). It should be `expect(MyComponent.instance().printSomething()).to.equal('output')`